# imagecopyresampled error in PHP

Tags: php, image-resizing

I'm at a loss here. I've successfully uploaded everything and adjusted the quality of the file with the `imagejpeg()` command, however, my `imagecopyresampled` function seems to be giving me an error:

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given on line 394

```
    $imgRaw = $_FILES[$file]['name'];
    $imgRawTemp = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];

    $nameExtract = explode(".", $imgRaw);

    $ext = $nameExtract[count($nameExtract)-1];

    $imgAll = getimagesize($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);

    $uploadedName = time().uniqid()."_original.";

    $dir = "usrPld/";

    $thisImg = $dir.$uploadedName.$ext;

    if($imgAll['mime'] == 'image/jpeg' || $imgAll['mime'] == 'image/png')
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($imgRawTemp, $thisImg))
        {

            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $imgAll;

            $thumbnailWidth = 250;
            $viewingWidth = 910;

            $thumbHeight = $thumbnailWidth*($height/$width);
            $viewingHeight = $viewingWidth*($height/$width);

            if($imgAll['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
            {
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($thisImg);
            }
            else if($imgAll['mime'] == 'image/png')
            {
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($thisImg);
            }

            $newName = time().uniqid().".jpg";
            $newName2 = time().uniqid().".jpg";

            if($width > $viewingWidth)
            {
                if(imagejpeg($image, $dir.$newName, 100))
                {
                    if(imagecopyresampled($dir.$newName2, 
                            $dir.$newName, 
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 
                            $viewingWidth, 
                            $viewingHeight, 
                            $width, 
                            $height))
                    {
                        unlink($thisImg);
                        unlink($dir.$newName);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(imagejpeg($image, $dir."no_".$newName, 100))
                {
                    unlink($thisImg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "format error";
    }
```

Oddly enough, I checked `$height` (because that's where the error is directing to) and it's outputting a number like it should.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: looks like you are not passing it an image. parameter 1 is `dst_image`

Comment: They are both ints...

Comment: The destination image is what it is there.

Comment: You put a string path, not an image resource object.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Ah yes, I tried using `$image` as the resource object, however, I got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$height is not your problem. You're passing directory paths as the first two parameters to imagecopyresampled() but they need to be image resources.  So you need to do something like this first:

```
$destImage = imagecreatetruecolor($viewingWidth, $viewingHeight);
$sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir.$newName);
```

Then pass them into your function:

```
if(imagecopyresampled($destImage, 
                        $sourceImage, 
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 
                        $viewingWidth, 
                        $viewingHeight, 
                        $width, 
                        $height))
```

Then, presumably you'd want to write the $destImage to your $dir.$newName2 path.